# Regular Expression that validates a list of port numbers (1-65535) across multiple lines

Tags: angular, regex, customvalidator, angular-validation

I am looking for a regular expression to match valid port numbers (1-65535) listed in a text area. The input will look like this:

```
80
80
25
53
110
---
---
```

and so on, so I need an expression that is able to handle validation in this way. Across multiple lines, unlimited times, be it that the user will be able to list as many port numbers as they need.. I have already taken a crack at writing my own expression and also using and expression I found.

```
^((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))$
```

which only does about half of what I need. Validates the number perfectly. but breaks as soon white space or a new line is created. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some samples that should match and not match. Your multiline sample should be a full match from start to end? What about the `---` ? Whitespace only at start/end of lines?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My bad the --- , was just suppose to indicate that more port numbers can be provided. A correct match would be a list like this:  80  25  110  and so on. A negative match would be just be any letters what so ever in the string, or any number over 65535 in the list example:  80A  65536  0

Comment: Sorry for the formatting issues but no port number will never be on the same line. it will always be in list format by the user in the text area.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add the whitespace and new lines to the expression? something like that:

```
^(((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))[\s\r\n]+)+$
```

Comment: I did try a variation of that but must've had the syntax wrong because this worked like a charm! I just added a few question marks to get exactly what I wanted and it worked! Thank you for the answer.